# CSS grow child to parent's max width

Tags: html, css

There are plenty of questions on how to make a parent's width that of it's child that are suggested as similar questions, this is not what I want.

I am working on theming a piece of software for branding purposes, I do not control the software and only have access to CSS modifications, so JavaScript or modifying the DOM is out of the question or this would be trivial.

Using CSS only, is it possible to achieve the following.

I have a container div that holds two columns, the main content area, and a sidebar. The sidebar contains multiple divs that wrap content for different sidebar elements. The content of these sidebar elements are designed to be scaled to 100% width of it's parent, which works when the parent has a fixed width, which is by default 25% of the container.

What we need is for the sidebar to disappear when it's content is hidden. The content within each sidebar element can be set to `display: none`, but when all the elements are hidden the sidebar still takes up empty space. The example below using a `min-width: fit-content` and a max width of the 25% which was previously it's fixed size, which works fine for hiding the sidebar when the content is hidden, but the content in the sidebar doesn't grow. Is there a way to make the content inside of `.sidebarElementWrapper` below, grow to fit the max-width of `#sidebarArea`

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
#contentArea {
    width: 100%;
    background: #A84652;
}
#sidebarArea {
    max-width: 25%;
    min-width: fit-content;
    background: #4262C2;
}
.sidebarElement {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px;
    background: #8b8b8b;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2c2c2c;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="contentArea">
    </div>
    <div id="sidebarArea">
        <div class="sidebarElementWrapper">
            <div class="sidebarElement">Sidebar Element 1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebarElementWrapper">
            <div class="sidebarElement">Sidebar Element 2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

To hide the content of a sidebar element, the `.sidebarElement` is set to `display: none`, not the wrapper, just of note. Since the wrapper still exists, and the content isn't removed, just hidden, the `:empty` pseudo-selector also doesn't work.

Edit: Just to clarify as I don't think it was clear after reading through this again, when the content is hidden the sidebar should be gone, doesn't matter how whether it's through `display:none` or width or some other mechanism. When there is sidebar content it should be 25% the width of the container.

Edit again: Because of some comments, I'm going to attempt to explain this again.

The sidebar has a min and max width, it does not have a fixed width, the sidebar will scale to fit the content inside it. Because the sidebar does not have a fixed width, elements basing their width on 100% of the parent do not act like you may expect, instead the sidebar is defaulting to the min-width from what I can tell, which is the minimum width required to fit the content. I am not looking for this, I want the sidebar to extend out to 25% of the container width, which you can see if you copy this code into a file (because the snippet above will run in a smaller pane it may actually be wider than 25% so it may not be representative)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#contentArea {
  width: 100%;
  background: #A84652;
}

#sidebarArea {
  max-width: 25%;
  min-width: fit-content;
  background: #4262C2;
}

.sidebarElement {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px;
  background: #8b8b8b;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #2c2c2c;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="contentArea">
  </div>
  <div id="sidebarArea">
    <div class="sidebarElementWrapper">
      <div class="sidebarElement">Sidebar Element 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebarElementWrapper">
      <div class="sidebarElement">Sidebar Element 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the end, I have a div with a min and max width, and a child element using a percent. The percent width (ie. `width:100%`) does not scale the child to the element's max width, but 100% of the current width, so no, the code as above does not achieve what I need.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You want the content of the sidebar to all have 100% width of the parent, right? That's already the case asa div elements do so by default. You also want the sidebar to hide if the containing blocks are hidden with `display: none`, correct? If that's the case then the code already does that. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: They don't though. If you copy that HTML code into a file and open it the sidebar is very thin, only being the minimum width required to fit the content. I want the sidebar to take up 100% of the max-width, setting the width to a percentage doesn't base the size on max-width. The sidebar has a max width of 25% of the container, yet the sidebar doesn't take anywhere near that much space. I want the content width to grow to make it take that much. If I set the sidebar width explicitly to 25% it looks fine, but doesn't disappear when the sidebar is empty.

Comment: Who edited the post? I intentionally did not want the second code block to be a snippet, because it doesn't run properly in this, notice how the height isn't 100% of the canvas and unless you run it expanded of full screen then the canvas is too small to see the issue. I posted that code for the intent of people copying and pasting it into a file to view if the snipped above it doesn't work. I even said this directly above the snippet... @j08691

Comment: I think the assumption, "the sidebar will scale to fit the content inside it.", is dead-wrong. As you stated in your stylesheet the sidebar (`#sidebarArea`) will take up 25% of it's parent's width, which is what I'm seeing in the snippet above. Looks good to me!

I'm having a hard time understanding your problem.. If you want to hide the sidebar when it's contents are empty, don't give it a width or height & let it's children determine the *fixed* size (seeing percentages won't work). This way, the sidebar will disappear if it has no content

Comment: Just run the code... You can see that it does not, IO don't understand all of these comments saying it does when I want when you can look yourself and see that NO. the 25% is the MAX width. The sidebar area will not automatically become that large unless the content it contains is that wide. Run the code snippet above either expanded or in full page and then see if the sidebar takes up 25% of the page, because it doesn't, you'll see it takes up only as much as is necessary to fit the content. This doesn't require guesswork, you can literally run it yourself.

Comment: "don't give it a width or height & let it's children determine the fixed size" I can't. I already don't give the sidebar a width, I set it's bounds only. I can not set the fixed width of elements inside the sidebar because the requirements are 25% of the container width. If I set a fixed value like 200px that will only be 25% at a very specific resolution. And as you stated percentages won't work for the children elements for this. I'm not asking if percentages will work, or if what I have currently should grow, I'm asking what would achieve the aim.

Comment: Does removing `min-width: fit-content;` resolve the issue? And side note, to answer your comment earlier, you can clearly see that I edited your question. If you don't agree with it you can either rollback to an earlier version or re-edit it.

Comment: If I remove the min-width: fit-content it gets even thinner, it gets small enough that the text in the example actually wraps so the number goes to the next line. So no, that does not fix it. Whatever i set the min-width to is the size that the sidebar ends up being. This isn't good because fit-content will not get me to the sidebar's max width unless the content is that wide, but setting any value that's not based on the content means the sidebar would never disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it, fill-available.

```
.sidebarElement {
    width: 100vw;
    ...
    max-width: fill-available;
    max-width: stretch;
    max-width: -webkit-fill-available;
    max-width: -moz-available;
}
```

Once this is done, the min-width on #sidebarArea can be removed.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#container {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
#contentArea {
    width: 100%;
    background: #A84652;
}
#sidebarArea {
    max-width: 25%;
    background: #4262C2;
}
.sidebarElement {
    width: 100vw;
    padding: 12px;
    background: #8b8b8b;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #2c2c2c;

    max-width: fill-available;
    max-width: stretch;
    max-width: -webkit-fill-available;
    max-width: -moz-available;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="contentArea">

        </div>
        <div id="sidebarArea">
            <div class="sidebarElementWrapper">
                <div class="sidebarElement">Sidebar Element 1</div>
            </div>
            <div class="sidebarElementWrapper">
                <div class="sidebarElement">Sidebar Element 2</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```